# Getting the index of the minimum value of a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, indexing

I have DataFrames `dfSide0` and `dfSide1` with different number of rows but same columns:

```
  'distoperator' 'Name'         'camera_row'
0  67.3350       'End of Coil'  'a'
1  1331.4001     'Dent'         'b'
2  130.8350      'Oil'          'a'
3  859.2139      'Black Line'   'f'
```

What I want is:

1. To get the minimum, absolute of all possible subtractions between the values of `dfSide0['distoperator']` and `dfSide1['distoperator']` but only when the condition `dfSide0['camera_row'] == dfSide1['camera_row']` is True.
2. To get the `dfSide1['Name']` value for each one of the above values.

My code so far is:

```
temp_operator = []
temp_op_defect = []
k = -1
for i in dfSide0['distoperator']:
    k = k + 1
    j = dfSide0.index[k]
    c = min(abs(i - dfSide1['distoperator'][dfSide1['camera_row'] == dfSide0['camera_row'][j]]))
    h = dfSide1.index(min(abs(i - dfSide1['distoperator'][dfSide1['camera_row'] == dfSide0['camera_row'][j]])))
    s = dfSide1['Name'][h]
    temp_operator.append(c)
    temp_op_defect.append(s)
```

which gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-e794dd1800c7> in <module>()
      6     j = dfSide0.index[k]
      7     c = min(abs(i - dfSide1['distoperator'][dfSide1['camera_row'] == dfSide0['camera_row'][j]]))
----> 8     h = dfSide1.index(min(abs(i - dfSide1['distoperator'][dfSide1['camera_row'] == dfSide0['camera_row'][j]])))
      9     s = dfSide1['Name'][h]
     10     temp_operator.append(c)

TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable
```

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: Can you share the two dataframes?

Comment: They have few thousand rows each. How can I share them?

Comment: Please make sure to post a minimal and verifiable example so people can help you.

Comment: To solve this, make the problem simpler and try to find it for one specific camera row. I'd do it this way: filter for camera_row, then sort both filteres dfs by distoperator. Since they are sorted now, you need to loop through both at the same time,in sorting order to check for minimum. A easy way is to use more-intertools (https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.peekable), which allows you to look(peek) at the current object before deciding to take the next from from the first or the second dataframe. (Taking in order means you take the lower of the two).

Comment: /2 whenever you find a minimum, remember both values. After the loop, locate the rows with that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the idxmin() method on the list created for every i:

```
temp_operator = []
temp_op_defect = []
k = -1
for i in dfSide0['distoperator']:
    k = k + 1
    c = min(abs(i - dfSide1['distoperator'][dfSide1['camera_row'] == dfSide0['camera_row'][k]]))
    h = abs(i - dfSide1['distoperator'][dfSide1['camera_row'] == dfSide0['camera_row'][k]]).idxmin()
    f = dfSide1['Name'][h]
    temp_operator.append(c)
    temp_op_defect.append(f)
```

It seems to work!